# IOS and Android Automation (single getDriver on later pages)

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, automation, automated-tests

I am automating all the Mobile frontend (features) (IOS and Android). I am refactoring a code and want to make it practical and clean for future refactorings. 
What I did: I created a class to create my AndroidDriver and created another class to create my IOSDriver. Both return driver. 
The problem is that when I create the next pages, I need to tell if it's IOS.driver () or android.driver () to be able to do the findElements and all that is entitled. 
How do I proceed? 
Is there a way I can create another class to be able to do an IF / ELSE and call this base page method on future pages?

Page Driver IOS (class driverIOS):

```
public static IOSDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
if (driver == null) {
createDriver();
}
return driver;
}
```

Page Driver Android (class driverAndroid):

```
public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
if (driver == null) {
createDriver();
}
return driver;
}
```

Parameter that tells if the test is IOS or Driver:

```
//Or IOS or Android
public static String SO = "IOS";
```

JAVA > Selenium > Appium.

Do you know my question?!?!!

I wait and thanks in advance

Comment: Someone??! !!!?!

Answer (score 0):

The core problem in this case is that even when you are able to invoke drivers separately, you will need to carry the same driver throughout your tests. Your tests will fail because you surely are passing diff capabilities for both ie Device and OS so this wouldn't work.

Only solution to this problem is by doing this via BDD frameworks where you put tags for both iOS and Android tests and this way you are able to separate both. I would strongly recommend **CodeceptJS** for the resolution of your problem. CodeceptJS has built in methods to support both iOS and Android tests in a single repository.